# Is there a way to iterate through all ASP.NET MVC 2 session keys?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'd like to get a list of all the session variable names.

something like:

```
foreach(Key name in HttpContext.Session.Keys)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code works! Just use `string` not `Key`

```
foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
{
    var value = Session[key];
}
```

Or an alternative

```
for (int i = 0; i < Session.Contents.Count; i++)
{
    var key = Session.Keys[i];
    var value = Session[i];
}
```